# Did Ukraine set up Russia on the MH17 incident?

Tags: aviation, war, russia, ukraine, mh17

Rebels shot several planes of Ukraine in the last days, after they got their hands on that missile system.

Some say that because of this, Ukraine flight control specifically gave directions to the plane to fly within that zone, knowing that the rebels could shoot it down like they did theirs

http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2014-07-17/was-flight-mh-17-diverted-over-restricted-airspace

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXQ_8_KUT3w

Comment: Where's the link to this claim?

Comment: It's like all over the news

Comment: In which case you can add a link.  Your news sources may not be the same as others.

Comment: but what if it was on tv?

Comment: What channel and at what time, where's a link to the transcript? Or a link to the video...

Comment: A google source revealed no examples of this claim. Can you give an example of media reporting this accusation?

Comment: Perhaps one needs to check Russian controlled TV stations?

Comment: Note to OP: none of the added links make the claim. They both make the claim that the plane was diverted. In the second link there's more than one claim, but we've already handled the "timestamp" one. in another question.

Comment: They insinuate that by diverting it, Ukr. authorities tried to get it shot down. There another Q about the polish plane without any links or "notable claims" as you call it, and it's not closed.

Comment: This claim is rolling around Russian forums and has its share of supporters, along the "it was the Malaysian plane lost in Indian Ocean, captured by US military and dropped over Ukraine full of dead bodies", as well as "it was shot by Ukrainian fighters". Believe me, there is a fair amount of people passionately defending these claims. But yes, I didn't find anything definitive in English, only in Russian...

Comment: @sashkello, links in other languages are acceptable to show notability, just provide a translation for them.

Comment: There's [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/22628/14836) to quite similar question, that perfectly proves, that deadly MH17 flight was on **the same path as for past weeks**. I found more evidences in the media, that flight was not rerouted, than your claims, that it was.